# In clojure how can I test if a a symbol has been defined?

Tags: clojure

I would like to see if a symbol has been "def" ed, but I can't see any ifdef syntax

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
user> (resolve 'foo)
nil
user> (def foo 3)
#'user/foo
user> (resolve 'foo)
#'user/foo
```

Answer (score 8):

`resolve` or `ns-resolve` may do what you're looking for:

```
user> (def a 1)
#'user/a
user> (def b)
#'user/b
user> (resolve 'a)
#'user/a
user> (resolve 'b)
#'user/b
user> (resolve 'c)
nil
```

To get a boolean:

```
user> (boolean (resolve 'b))
true
```

EDIT: per MayDaniel's comment, this isn't exactly what you asked for, but it will get you there. Here's an implementation of `bounded?` (probably not the best name):

```
(defn bounded? [sym]
  (if-let [v (resolve sym)]
    (bound? v)
    false))

user> (map bounded? ['a 'b 'c])
(true false false)
```

Comment: Well, no. 'b is resolved, but it's unbound. This isn't what the questioner wants.

Comment: I think it would be rare that one would actually need `true` and `false`.  Since `resolve` returns a truthy value if the symbol is bound, and a falsey value, `nil`, if it's unbound, one could often use `resolve` as is.  `(if (resolve 'c) "The symbol is bound, dude."  "Whaa?? That symbol's unbound!")`

Answer (score 4):

Can use find-var for this

```
(bound? (find-var 'user/y))
```

Comment: This returns a null pointer exception if `y` is unbound in `user`, because `find-var` returns `nil` in that case.