# Clojure: resolve declares symbol

Tags: clojure, symbols, resolve, declare

I get some weird behaviour when checking if a symbol can be resolved.

```
user=> ok
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: ok in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)
user=> (resolve 'ok)
nil
user=> (if (resolve 'ok) "bla" (def ok 'ok))
"bla"
user=> ok
#<Unbound Unbound: #'user/ok>
user=> (def ok 'ok)
#'user/ok
user=> ok
ok
```

Can anyone tell me where this might come from? Is this behaviour intended?

Comment: What version of Clojure are you using? I don't see this on 1.2.1

Comment: @spacemanaki: Interesting, I just reproduced this in both 1.2.1 and 1.3 Something strange is definitely happening.

Comment: My mistake, second reference to `ok` resulted in an exception instead of returning an `#<Unbound...>` object, and I didn't pay attention. For me, on 1.2.1 `(resolve 'ok)` inside the `if` does result in `ok` being declared.

Comment: You'll find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4908367/506721) to another question useful. His function `bounded?` seems to do the solve your problem. I replaced `resolve` with it in your example and it worked. As for this behavior, I hope we'll get an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(def ok "whatever")` creates a variable named `ok` *at compile time*. The compiler scans the whole form to compile it, discovers that you will be defining a var named `ok`, and creates it for you (with no binding), before your form is actually executed. When the `def` form is actually executed, the runtime value of the expression will be assigned to the var `user/ok`. In your example, this never happens, because the var has already been created, and the `if` branch goes the other way.

Using `bound?` as a substitute is a terrible idea, as it tests something quite different: whether the named var (which must exist) has a binding, either permanent or thread-local.

Comment: sounds logical. But then why does `(if (resolve 'x) x (def x 'x))` yield `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: x in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)`? Or does he try to evaluate x before he creates the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Since I only use it inside a macro I now use it as follows

```
(defmacro bla [x]
    (if (resolve x) x `(def ~x '~x)))
```

And now it works since def is inside the quoted form and evaluated after resolve.